# Splitting cnn layer in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to get rid of some channels in CNN. It consists of two models which are combined to create a simple model.

It creates correct output but in intermediate layer but still gives an error later.

```
def highAccuracyModelTillConv2(input_img): 
  conv1_1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], activation='elu', name = 'HighAccuracyConv1'))(input_img)
  conv1_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
  conv2_1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation= 'elu', name = 'HighAccuracyConv2',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))(conv1_2)
  conv2_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2_1)  
  return conv2_1
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
def cifar10ClassifierTransfer(input_img, conv2_high):

  # Add additional inputs to 

  conv1_1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], activation='elu'))(input_img)
  conv1_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
  conv2_1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation= 'elu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))(conv1_2)
  channels = [1,2,4]
  branch_outputs = []
  orig_channel = conv2_1
  branch_outputs.append(orig_channel)
  for i in channels:
      # Slicing the ith channel:
      out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:, i])(conv2_high)
      # Setting up your per-channel layers (replace with actual sub-models):
      layer_out =  keras.backend.expand_dims(out, axis = 3)
      branch_outputs.append(layer_out)
  out = Concatenate()(branch_outputs)
  print(out.shape)

  out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(out)

  return out
```

```
high_acc_output = highAccuracyModelTillConv2(input_img)
modelFilt = Model(input_img, 
              cifar10ClassifierTransfer(input_img,
              high_acc_output))
```

This is the error I get when I create the model despite correct correct value of intermediate output. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(?, 32, 32, 35)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-257-685f377c5c1a> in <module>()
      3 modelFilt = Model(input_img, 
      4               cifar10ClassifierTransfer(input_img,
----> 5               high_acc_output))
      6 # #data augmentation
      7 # datagen = ImageDataGenerator(

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1323             ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
   1324         """
-> 1325         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
   1326 
   1327         # Prevent cycles.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error usually means we passed in some type of object other than a Keras Layer. Most of your code looks OK on its face, but this line of code needs to be wrapped in a Lambda layer:

```
layer_out =  keras.backend.expand_dims(out, axis = 3)
```

Change it to something like:

```
layer_out = Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.expand_dims(x, axis = 3))(out)
```

In general, any time we drop down to the Tensorflow backend, we have to use a lambda layer because backend operate on tensors, not Keras Layers.

Comment: don't forget to upvote and accept so I get that sweet, sweet Karma!